# How to solve this error in Android? java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:

Tags: java, android, .net, button, textview

I dont know what is exactly problem, But I am getting error like:
Even I also checking all paths, and it is correct but still it will get error.

java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx

My Code:

```
package com.example.mytest;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    public final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
    public String URL = "www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";

    TextView tv;

    public static String TAG = "MyTest";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity Started");
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        Request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");

        // URL=URL.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        Log.d(TAG, "URL:"+URL);

        AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

        try {
            // HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            Log.d(TAG, "aht:" + aht);

            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope
                    .getResponse();

            // Object resultString = (Object)soapEnvelope.getResponse();

            Log.d(TAG, "result String=" + resultString);

            tv.setText("Status: " + resultString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: ", e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I dont know what is exact problem but I am getting error like:

```
02-01 21:07:01.264: D/MyTest(1068): MainActivity Started
02-01 21:07:01.534: D/MyTest(1068): Error: 
02-01 21:07:01.534: D/MyTest(1068): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx
02-01 21:07:01.534: D/MyTest(1068):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:275)
02-01 21:07:01.534: D/MyTest(1068):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:159)
02-01 21:07:01.534: D/MyTest(1068):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.<init>(ServiceConnectionSE.java:65)
02-01 21:07:01.534: D/MyTest(1068):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.<init>(ServiceConnectionSE.java:61)
02-01 21:07:01.534: D/MyTest(1068):     at org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidServiceConnection.<init>(AndroidServiceConnection.java:27)
02-01 21:07:01.534: D/MyTest(1068):     at org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport.getServiceConnection(AndroidHttpTransport.java:35)
02-01 21:07:01.534: D/MyTest(1068):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:124)
02-01 21:07:01.534: D/MyTest(1068):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add `http://` before the `www...` or `https://`.

```
public String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
```

Comment: I was done with new correction, but now new error is comming, java.io.IOException: Hostname <www.w3schools.com> was not verified

Comment: @GaneshKatikar - ask a new question ... after checking that it  hasn't already been asked and answered.

Comment: I am correcting this changes, but now new error is comming like: SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit.'; faultactor: 'null' detail: Is any Solution now

Comment: i had http://182.12.23 like this and getting this issue

Comment: but I am using a proxy

Answer (score 2):

you missed the protocol `http://`

```
public String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
```

**NOTE:**
If you just need to convert from Celsius to Fahrenhiet ot vice-versa  you could try this:

```
function C2F ( C ) {
var F = eval ((C x 9 / 5) +32)
return ( F ); }

function F2C ( F ) {
var C = eval ( F - 32 ) * 5 / 9;
return ( C ); }
```

Comment: I am correcting this changes, but now new error is comming like: SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit.' faultactor: 'null' detail:

Comment: is `tempuri.org` the host you're using or just an example ?

Comment: Actually I dont want formula at all. I just want to call that web service to show output